# 404 errors when accessing https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo

Tags: google-oauth

We're sometimes see 404 errors when accessing https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?alt=json in our application.

```
apiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?alt=json returned "Not Found">
```

The overall rate is low, though it is a bit weird to be getting back this error given that this endpoint does exist.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try again? I think this was a temporary outage.

Thanks for reporting the issue.

Comment: We aren't seeing 404's anymore, but again at low rate we're always seeing some userinfo failures. This is highly problematic as it means some key features of our product that use Google Drive stop working in this scenario.

    HttpError 503 when requesting     https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?alt=json